# How to strech clip-path footer to the full width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a footer on my website that must fill the full width of each page, but here is what I get:

[image]

It doesn't fill the full width of the page and, moreover, doesn't stick to the bottom. Here's the code I use for it:

```
.root {
    margin: 25% 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 336px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    clip-path: polygon(0 11%, 4% 44%, 24% 15%, 38% 29%, 66% 7%, 80% 27%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 99%);
    background: var(--text-marked);
}

.firstLine,
.secondLine {
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Montserrat medium, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.secondLine {
   margin-top: 12%;
   font-size: 20px;
}
```

Here's the code of the container div:

```
.container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    color: var(--text);
}
```

Here's the code of the footer:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './Footer.module.css'

const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.root}>
            <p className={styles.firstLine}>Designed by Mikhail Shkarubski</p>
            <p className={styles.secondLine}>For HSE Global Scholarship Competition</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Footer
```

Are there any solutions without `calc()` or negative margins?

Comment: insert html pls

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I've attached the code of my footer

Comment: did you reset margins on the <p> or added a 1px padding on the parent ? (collapsing margin) ?

Comment: It looks like you have either padding or margin to the parent container or root element (make sure body has margin as 0, by default browser uses 8px margin to body). To make it fix to the bottom either use absolute or fixed position property, if you are setting it to absolute then make sure you are also setting its parent to relative or else it will act as fixed.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand your problem, but if you set rules - `box-sizing: border-box;`, `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` for the `body` tag, then your problem is solved?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus all the CSS I have is displayed in my questions. There are no margins or padding, except margin-top, which is set to 25%.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov well, I've tried ```box-sizing: border-box;``` but it didn't work. And, actually, I already have set ```margin: 0;``` and ```padding: 0;```.

Comment: As of now there is no other way than to make the full width containers without using the calc or negative margins, here's the link for reference: https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Comment: maybe it is just about body's margin ? https://jsfiddle.net/jkvqx8au/